# Are OLAP Cubes Self generating?

Tags: sql-server, olap, database-partitioning, olap-cube, multidimensional-cube

A month ago I was given a ticket to work on a SQL Server Olap cube that didn't have any data for March 2023. I discovered one of the issues was that the partitions in the cube were expired. I created new partitions, reprocessed, and all is good.

Now I have two other cubes that I recently noticed have partitions that are going to expire soon. At first I assumed I would need to update them the same way I did the previous cube. However, I pulled some code I had for these two cubes from 9 months ago, and I noticed that the partitions in that code were not updated to where they currently are. This suggests that the partitions are updating automatically, but the first cube I worked on didn't update its partitions automatically.

In general, do olap cubes have a setting that automatically creates a partition when one is about to expire? I understand that there could be a procedure in our SQL Server warehouse that does this, but I haven't found such and am unsure if this can be initiated by a process setting of some kind.

If the cubes do not automatically generate new partitions, is possible to see when the most recent partition was created?